# Slack App error: "New Request URL: Your URL didn't respond with the value of the challenge parameter"

Tags: slack, slack-api, ngrok

I created a Slack bot using the Slack API. The bot app presently runs on my local machine on port 5000. I have forwarded the port to a public IP using `ngrok`. The bot was working perfectly until yesterday.
Now I get the error message shown in the screen shot attached when I add the new URL from `ngrok` as the Slack events endpoint.

[image: "your url didn't respond with the value of the challenge parameter", "clallenge_failed"]

Has anyone had a similar problem? Do you know why in the sent http post request the challenge parameter and token are empty?

Comment: I have had a similar type of error when using slack bot with ngrok. This occurs if your ngrok port is not turned on with proper configuration. Restart ngrok and try again with a different port. When getting such error on api/slack view the terminal with ngrok to find what causes the issue. In such case you can find 401 error, and 200 OK if the connection is stable and authorized

Comment: Good to know. Fortunately my issue got fixed when I updated the slack eventsapi package from 3.0.0 to 3.0.1, which was a pretty recent update :)

Answer (score 2):

Backend server has to be running for authentication. Start the backend server (e.g., `python3 app.py`, from [Slack's development docs](https://api.slack.com/start/building/bolt-python#initialize), if you're building with Python), and then hit retry to verify the request URL

Answer (score 1):

No running server. The server has to be running prior to authenticating, at least for the initial challenge event verification. It would fail if my server(nodejs/vsCode Terminal) wasn't running while ngrok was running in a seperate terminal(terminal)

Answer (score 0):

The failure can be due to

1. The Firewall blocking the connection in and out.
2. Your system time is incorrect, causing time sync failure.

Turn off the firewall and check your system time as well.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my flask port, and changed in ngrok command too:

From:

```
ngrok http 5000
```

To:

```
ngrok http 5001
```